# How to display a Date Picker when you click on a Select option in Materia-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple material-ui select that shows different dates and one of the options is custom, is there a way to display a Date Picker once I click on the custom option? if not what other options do I have to achieve something similar to that.

Thank you in advance for your help!!

this is my default view:

[image]

This is how I want it to look like when I click on the custom option:
[image]

This is my code:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import EventSharpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/EventSharp';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    minWidth: 150,
  },
  iconOpen:{
    transform:'none'
  },
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [date, setDate] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setDate(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Date Created</InputLabel>
        <Select
          IconComponent = {EventSharpIcon}
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={date}
          onChange={handleChange}
          classes={{icon:classes.icon, iconOpen:classes.iconOpen}}
          MenuProps={{getContentAnchorEl: () => null}}
        >
          {
            dateOptions.map((dateOption) => (
              <MenuItem value={dateOption.value} key={dateOption.value}>
                {dateOption.date}
              </MenuItem>
            ))
          }
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      
    </div>
  );
}

const dateOptions = [
  {
    date: 'Today',
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    date: 'Yesterday',
    value: -1,
  },
  {
    date: 'Last 7 Days',
    value: -7,
  },
  {
    date: 'Last 14 Days',
    value: -14,
  },
  {
    date: 'Last 30 Days',
    value: -30,
  },
  {
    date: 'Last 90 Days',
    value: -90,
  },
  {
    date: 'Custom',
    value: 0,
  }
]
```

Comment: what will be the value of your state `date` when you select `custom` ? Is it 0 ?

Comment: { date === 0 && ( render your DatePicker Component ) }

Comment: @Shyam The value of the custom will eventually be whatever date range I pick from the DatePicker. I'm not sure if i'm following { date === 0 && ( render your DatePicker Component ) }